# Must an unbounded set in a metric space be infinite?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I'm new to real analysis and topology. Recently, I'm reading baby rudin. Occasionally, I've a question: does a set is unbounded implies the set is infinite in metric space? I think the statement is right, but I can't prove it.

Please give the strict proof. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try showing instead that every finite set is bounded. Find a ball which contains every point in the set.

Comment: Boundedness is not a useful concept in general metric spaces since any metric is equivalent to a bounded metric. Boundedness is useful in normed linear spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes (if metric spaces are assumed to be non-empty).

Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ denote a metric space.

Suppose that a set $S\subseteq X$ is finite and let $x\in X$.

If we take $r>\max\{d(x,y)\mid y\in S\}$ then $S\subseteq B(x,r)=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)<r\}$, showing that $S$ is bounded.

That means that unbounded sets cannot be finite, hence are infinite.

---

Note: this answer preassumes that metric spaces are not empty. If $X=\varnothing$ then the finite set $\varnothing$ is unbounded since $X=\varnothing$ is not contained in any ball centered at some $x\in X$. This because balls like that simply do not exist in that situation.

Comment: Whoa! An unbounded set of zero diameter!

Comment: Definitions make miracles happen.:-)

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. The anatomy of the empty set does have some surprises, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

If $A=\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ is a finite set in a metric space $(X,d)$, then pick $x_0 \in X$ an let

$c:= \max\{d(x_0,a_1),...,d(x_0,a_n)\}$. Then $A$ is contained in the closed ball with radius $c$ and midpoint $x_0$.

Hence $A$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $S$ is finite. Then there exists $x^*\in S$ such that $\|x\|\leq \|x^*\|$ for all $x\in S$. Clearly $S$ cannot be unbounded.

Comment: Huhu ! We are in a metric space, not in a normed space !

Comment: Yeah, we're not a normed space.